# JetBrains Toolbox in Windows to install IDEs to specific folders other than ones within drive C

Tags: jetbrains-toolbox

I want to install PyCharm, PhpStorm, etc. into some folder on drive **D**.
Though JetBrains Toolbox not having the option to do so in my view.

So the question is that is it possible to customize the installation folder for JetBrains IDEs when installing via Toolbox?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can configure the install location for apps in the Toolbox settings. However, this will install ALL apps under the specified directory (and move existing ones there). If you want to define a specific install location for each IDE, then that is not possible... yet.

Also see [this support question](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000047724-Using-same-Toolbox-installation-for-multiple-accounts-on-same-machine-Ubuntu-). The second answer explains how you can manually update the `install_location` property in `.settings.json`. This will change the install location for future installations, and your existing apps will not be moved.

Comment: Although this question answers the OP's question, I believe giving a link to the answer should not be an answer. The Answer below provides more details.

Answer (score 13):

[**Windows 10**] I found a manual location changing option that is not well explained on any forum.

After you install Jetbrains Toolbox, if you cannot change the Tool install location from the app UI, and it goes into "Failing to change location, because application is in use, or something like that" if you are trying to change from there, close the Toolbox application(kill it from Task manager, or close it from the toolbar), and after you go to the default installation location of the Toolbox app(more info about this, here: https://toolbox-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000978804-Where-are-the-IDEs-located-on-my-hard-drive-) and open **.settings.json** file

In the **.settings.json** file you need to add/update the following code line:

```
"install_location": "<default_location>",
```

There, add your desired install location instead of <*default_location*> if there exists the line in the file. If this line does not exist, add it the begining of the file. Don't forget to add the " , " in the end of the line.

Please help to spread this message to our fellow friends who are using Jetbrains Toolbox and are having this ***problem***.

Comment: Thanks, this should be the right answer, this helped me!

Answer (score 8):

The location of the setting in the UI seems to change with subsequent Toolbox versions.
Currently it's under Toolbox > cogwheel icon > Toolbox App Setting > Tools > Tools install location.

Toolbox operates under current user permissions, not as administrator and it cannot ask for privileged access yet. In partical term it means if you wan't to install it under "C:\Program Files" you will have create "JetBrains", or whatever root directory you want, manually there, in your preferred file manager, then apply permission settings allowing you current user to write to that directory.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like they invested some time in this. No need to play around with config files anymore:

- Open your toolbox application
- Open settings.
- Open tab "Tools"
- Change "tools install location"
- Hit "apply changes"
- Wait until files are moved

[image]
[image]

Comment: Installing this on 2023-08-18, the "Tools install location" is not editable to me.

Comment: I can click "Show" also, but a button "Change" is not visible at all

Answer (score 2):

Finally, since the 31st of October there has been a new version (2.1) of ToolBox available which had brought back the option to change the installation location of all IDE's.

[See the latest dev response to this issue opened on youtrack.jetbrains.com](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-9575/Enable-changing-install-location)

**You can get the latest Toolbox version from here: [Latest version (2.1+)](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/nextversion/)**

***Edit (13 Nov 2023): the version 2.1 is now released as stable.***

Although, be wary:

> This is an early access version of the product
> You expressly acknowledge that this version of the product may not be reliable, may not work as intended and may contain errors. Any use of the EAP product is at your own risk.

Also, I am surprised no one has mentioned creating a symbolic link from the original location to the location where you would want to move your installation. It is generally a working solution for many situations and I highly advise reading a bit about it.

Answer (score 1):

Despite setting the install attribute in the `.json` file, it still didn't work. I looked around and this doesn't seem like an issue they have addressed - [youtrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-3722/Toolbox-app-cant-change-tools-install-location)

I ended up installing it as standalone (Intellij Idea and Pycharm). During this installation it requests for the directory, so it sorts my problem.